# Bluetooth does not find any devices anymore on Focal - blueman-assistant crashes while searching

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, bluetooth

I am using Xubuntu 20.04 on a desktop with a USB Bluetooth dongle. Until a couple of days ago, everything worked fine.
Now, when booting up the system, Bluetooth first seems to work, but it cannot connect to previously paired devices anymore.
Deleting these devices (in order to re-pair - no pun intended) showed that it would not scan for new devices.
Calling `blueman-assistant` produces a crash report - this is the output when started in a terminal (even after a fresh reboot of the system):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/Base.py", line 81, in callback
    value = proxy.call_finish(result).unpack()
gi.repository.GLib.Error: g-io-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.InProgress: Operation already in progress (36)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/Base.py", line 90, in callback
    raise parse_dbus_error(e)
blueman.bluez.errors.DBusInProgressError:  Operation already in progress
```

Calling `bluetoothctl power on` succeeds...

```
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
```

... as well as `list`

```
[bluetooth]# list
Controller 00:15:83:3D:E0:55 joe [default]
```

also, `scan on` seems to work (except it won't find devices)

```
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 00:15:83:3D:E0:55 Discovering: yes
```

There have been no hardware changes to the system, just the regular package updates, including

```
linux-firmware
linux-generic
linux-headers-5.4.0-59
linux-headers-5.4.0-59-generic
linux-headers-5.4.0-60
linux-headers-5.4.0-60-generic
linux-headers-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-59-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-60-generic
linux-image-generic
linux-libc-dev:amd64
linux-modules-5.4.0-56-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-59-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-60-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-56-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-59-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-60-generic
```

What else can I try to get it up and running again?

Edit - additional info:
`dmesg | grep -i bluetooth` brings this:

```
[    5.119166] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.119180] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.119182] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.119184] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.119185] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    6.618854] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.618855] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.618858] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   14.340536] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   14.340541] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   14.340546] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[22012.620562] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000bdcb6757 failed to resubmit (2)
```

Comment: I'm having a somewhat similar issue with a new Bluetooth USB adapter that acts like it works, but doesn't find anything (in Xubuntu 22.04 on Cinnamon, with Blueman). I don't see any errors wtih `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`, though.